# try catch not catching in xCode simulator all of a sudden

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I have had this bit of code in my app for years:

```
 for (NSString* key in keyedValues) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@",key,[keyedValues objectForKey:key]);
        @try {
            [self setValue:[keyedValues objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) { // this assumes this is a date from our JSON
            [self setValue:[dfm dateFromString:[keyedValues objectForKey:key]] forKey:key];
        }
    }
```

It handles a weird date format I get from a webservice, if the data is funky an error is thrown and I format it in the catch.  Literally nothing has changed with this piece of code or the webservice for years.

Today in working on other things in my app in the simulator this code stopped working.  Meaning the error get's thrown in the try but just stops dead there and nothing goes to the catch.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but only in simulator. Exceptions get caught when running on physical devices. Is that your experience as well?

Comment: yep, exact same thing out of nowhere.  Same code for almost 4 years

Comment: is this with XCode 6.3.2?

Comment: Check this out on the apple forums, it might be related. I would definitely file a radar. I'm seeing something similar. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/267548?tstart=0